# SQL Server 2008 - scheduled copy of production database into test and development databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup-restoration

I wish to schedule a copy from my production database into two other databases.

The databases are located on same server (instance?). The databases are currently backed up to server hard drive every night and basing a solution on this backup would be fully satisfactory.

What is the best way to do this?

Any comments appreciated,

Anders, Denmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule a restore from the backup to the development database? It is not that hard. Use SQL Server Agent for that ;)

Comment: Very simple answer - but sometimes that just what you need ;-) I got it to work in first attempt...

Answer (score 1):

I think snapshot replication would fit your needs. Please refer here for further details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Regards, D.