# Scheduled copy of production database into test database

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, database-replication

My question is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/139501/sql-server-2008-scheduled-copy-of-production-database-into-test-and-developmen).

I've Two different severs (both SQL Server 2014 Std Edition). Production and Test. I want my test server to connect every night to the production server and copy/clone one database.

I Know I could schedule a backup in the Production server, put this backup in a shared folder and the restore it in the Test Server.

Is there any way to make the Test Server do all the job without using any shared folder?

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to automate the restore from my backups.  That way you get automatic testing thay your backup and restore procedures work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a program which does it all in TSQL. Or use an SSIS task

Have a look on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568157/copy-sql-server-data-from-one-server-to-another-on-a-schedule) for some more details

Answer (score 1):

Use the Copy Database Wizard.
- Right click the source database - Choose Tasks - Copy Database.

In the guide You can choose to create a schedule for the job also.